# Existence for $-\Delta u + u + f(u) =0$ when $f$ is a compact operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, elliptic-equations, linear-pde

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth domain and consider on it
$$-\Delta u + u + f(u) =0 $$
with $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$. Here $f\colon H^1(\Omega) \to H^1(\Omega)$ is a linear, compact operator, but I don't know if it is monotone and I don't have any sign information.

Is it possible to get existence for this equation (in eg. Sobolev spaces) without assuming that $\langle f(u), u \rangle$ can be "absorbed" into the lower order term $u$?

Comment: What do you mean by absorbed?

Comment: Probably Schauder's fixed point theorem could get us existence in $H_0^1(\Omega)$...

Comment: You might wnat to look into Fredholm alternative for non-zero right-hand sides

Comment: @daw Yep, was just thinking that :) Uniqueness seems a pain, though. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is linear, clearly $u=0$ is a solution.

Comment: Duh, of course.